# IntelliJ Project "JS Client and JVM Server | Gradle" does not work

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin, netty, ktor

when I create the stated project type with Intellij Ultimate 2019.2

and then build the project (F11)

following error appears:

[image: build error]

However when I run the SampleJvm.kt:
[image: run]

Netty start and everything seems fine.
Unfortunately the code is not working correctly:

[image: still an error]

The issue seems to be that the backend cannot find the
compiled testy.js, which shall be loaded as a resource
and then added to the HTML site:

[image: issue]

I uploaded the project for download:
https://file.io/Jj50Ow

Thank you so much for any advice,
Best Chris

Answer (score 0):

The js file is generated and packaged in a jar file, but the JVM server does not have a dependency on that JAR file and therefore it generates 404.

Open the build.gradle file and scroll to the bottom, add jsJar to the dependsOn and the classpath:

```
task run(type: JavaExec, dependsOn: [jvmJar, jsJar]) {
    group = "application"
    main = "sample.SampleJvmKt"
    classpath(configurations.jvmRuntimeClasspath, jvmJar, jsJar)
    args = []
}
```

And then you can run the app with gradle.

Answer (score 0):

At this time, the new project generator doesn't correctly handle multiplatform projects.

There is a working example with Ktor on the back-end and React on the front-end, including hot-reload for UI development:
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-full-stack-application-demo

I was able to get it working with Kotlin Gradle DSL, with a Spring Boot back-end (including being able to debug from IDE) and hot-reload of React front-end:
https://github.com/alexoooo/sample-multiplatform-boot-react

Note that Kotlin multiplatform projects are currently experimental, and some of the details are likely to change as the new IR is introduced: https://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2020/03/kotlin-1-4-m1-released/